# How can I create a file in Linux in a way that when I open it, it is actually running a process

Tags: linux, pipe, symlink, named-pipes

I have a set of `.sph` files which are actually audio `.wav` files plus some header.
I have a program called `sph2pipe` which converts these `.sph` files to normal audio `.wav` files.
I want to create some kind of symbolic link to these `.sph` files that when I read these links I would be actually reading the converted version of them.
Something like this:

```
ln -s "sph2pipe a.sph |" "a.wav"
ln -s "sph2pipe b.sph |" "b.wav"
```

So this way, I don't have to convert all audio files to `.wav` files and instead I just create links to `.sph` files and I want them to get converted on the fly.

I hope I made myself clear. I was thinking what I am looking for is a Named pipe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) but this would not be useful in my case since I need to read the `.wav` files several times.

EDIT-1: I don't have to use named pipes. I just thought this could be the solution.
Actually, in my case, these `.wav` files are needed to be read several times.

EDIT-2: I was wondering how Samba (or gvfs-smb) works. So the files are in the network but there is also a path available for them in my system like: /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=10.100.98.54,share=db/4a0a010a.sph. Can I do something like this? (I read .sph files from a specific path and .wav files come out :) )

EDIT-3: I came up with this so far:

keep_running.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

cmd = 'mkfifo 4a0a010a.wav'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

cmd = 'sph2pipe -f wav 4a0a010a.wv1 > 4a0a010a.wav'
while True:
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

And in shell:

```
./keep_running.py &
play 4a0a010a.wav 
play 4a0a010a.wav 
play 4a0a010a.wav
```

I can use the audio file as many times as I want.

What do you think would be the limitations of this implementation?
Would I be limited by the number of the processes that I can spawn? Because it looks like I need to spawn a process for each file.

Comment: How do you intend to play them? I mean do you want to double-click on them or must they appear as files that some music program can see them?

Comment: I have this java program that reads all the `.wav` files and converts those audio files to some kind of feature files.

Comment: This could nominally be accomplished with a named pipe and a background process, but I'm not convinced it's a good idea. What if two processes both open the file and start reading?

Comment: @tripleee Now that I have investigated more into named pipes, I don't think they are a good solution. See my edited question.

Comment: That's basically what (the latter part of) @BasileStarynkevitch' answer covers.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest but you didn't answer how many files you had so I was unable to say if it made any sense spawning that many processes - instead I got down voted without any explanation of why.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Your first answer was not related to my question because I already know how to convert them. I think I have around 326X10 + 49X40 files.

Comment: :-) It's kind of hard sometimes answering questions because, don't forget, I don't know how expert you are - so you may not want to create links because you don't know how to create them using a loop and you need 2,000 so it seems impossible to you yet it is quite easy and that could be a good, effective solution. So sometimes we get to a solution a step at a time and the first answer is not ideal but we home in on one - like we have done here hopefully :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it, it's a bad idea.

If you insist anyway, perhaps just out of curiosity, here's a proof of concept.

```
mkfifo a.wav
sph2pipe a.sph >a.wav &
```

Now, the results are available *once* in `a.wav` but once you have consumed them, they are gone, and a new instance of the background process has to be started if you need to do it again.

Sounds to me like a simple Makefile would serve your use case better (create missing files, recreate files which need to be updated, potentially remove temporary targets when the main target has successfully been made).

Answer (score 1):

No, a named pipe, or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), wants some *existing* process to write it (and another to read it). There is no magic that will start the writing process when some other process opens that fifo for reading.

You could provide your [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem (whose actions would produce the sound data). I am not sure that it worth the effort in your case.

<sup>Remember that several processes can read or write the same file at once.</sup>

Comment: I was wondering how Samba (or gvfs-smb) works. So the files are in the network but there is also a path available for them in my system like: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=10.100.98.54,share=db/4a0a010a.sph`. Can I do something like this? (I read .sph files from a specific path and .wav files come out :) )

Comment: @183.amir: Yes, you could write a CIFS server.  It's really the same concept as FUSE -- an existing kernel driver offers a filesystem which you can mount, and user-mode code provides the content.  FUSE should be faster since it doesn't have to work across a network.

Comment: Actually `.sph` files are stored across the local network and not on my computer. Could you provide an answer and explain more please?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Or, if you don't have more than a couple of 1000 files, you can spawn a process for each fifo that keeps sending the file to it repeatedly like this:

```
for f in *.sph; do
    mkfifo "${f}.wav"
    (while :; do sph2pipe "$f" > "${f}.wav"; done) &
done
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I am not at my computer but can you generate the WAV files automatically, use them, then delete them...

```
for f in *.sph; do
    sph2pipe "$f" > "${f}.wav"
done
```

Then use them,,,

Then delete

```
rm *.wav
```

Comment: I have a lot of .sph files and I cannot store all of them at once. And the java program that I use needs all of them.